# htaccess mod rewritten urls, 301 redirect on dynamic page?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am utilizing mod-rewrite and my htaccess file to translate query string urls to friendly ones. These are products that pull from a database and which populate a single dynamic php file - **product1.php**.

I introduced this rewrite function fairly recently and have seen my site traffic plummet. I am thinking this is because I need to add 301 redirects to the rewritten urls. (I have noticed a massive spike in url errors, mostly nonsensical, for some reason.)

Can you use 301 redirects if it's just one file (**product1.php**), only the url's are different; and, if so, how do you write it? I have searched this specific question, no luck.

FYI, here's what I have currently in my htaccess utilizing mod-rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On

#Redirect all requests missing "www"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]

#Truncate extension ".php" from requests
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]

#Look for the word "category" followed by slash, product type, slash, model name and model id, slash, product id
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^category/.*/.*/([0-9]+)$ product1.php?product-id=$1 [L,QSA]

#Rewrite static file url
RewriteRule ^category/subcategory/?$ subcategory-index.php [NC]
```

I have about forty of this last rewrite for the various static pages I am renaming.

Thanks :)

Comment: You're just internally routing specific requests to `/product1.php` which is not seen by search agents hence it won't impact your site traffic.

Comment: Hmm, unsure then of the huge drop in website traffic (it's unprecedented). Drop coincided with upload of htaccess seen above. I'm just concerned that there may be error(s) in my rewrites causing external links to error out instead of being able to connect to the site.

Comment: Yes you do need to look into your error.log to see all 404, 500 etc

Comment: Let me qualify that, drop also coincided with upload of updated site map, which following exact same protocols as previous.

Comment: My url errors tripled from about 500 to over 1,500, most of which are nonsensical (not sure where they came from). But some include current active urls.